# Deleting several lines in Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I get an invoice in Word, with extra "headers". The headers look like this:

[image: Invoice]

The arrows are pointing at variables that change from invoice to invoice.
Every document contains several invoices and a lot of these headers.

I need to identify and delete every one of them with page number 2 and upwards and leave the ones with page number 1.

I've used:

```
 Sub DeleteLines()
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
 Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory 
 With Selection.Find 
     .ClearFormatting 
     .Wrap = wdFindStop 
     .Text = "NO BOW A/S" 
     Do While .Execute 
          ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Line").Range.Delete 
     Loop 
End With 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not a code provider service dear, we can help you if you are stuck. Please post your effort.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't expect a code. I just wanted inspiration for what people would use in this example, since i am still a learner in VBA. I've used:

Comment: MS Word document contains Paragraphs. It does not contain lines. Seems, you want to delete second page only. Am i right?

Comment: No, i want to delete the ones with the numbers 2 or more, outside the "page. . . :"

So the ones with numbers 2, 3, 4, 5 etc

Comment: The image i have attached show what i want to delete. Only criteria is the "page number".